# AVRO schema's JSON looks valid but returns invalid from Kafka Schema Registry

Tags: avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to register an AVRO schema to Schema Registry. The schema contains a record and some fields. I post the schema as JSON to Schema Registry REST API and although the JSON look fine the server returns `curl : {"error_code":42201,"message":"Input schema is an invalid Avro schema"}`.

Could someone please have a look?

Powershell is used to produce the schema as JSON.

```
$type = @{namespace="customer-actions"; name="customer-enrollment"; 
          type="record"; 
          fields=@{name="id"; type="int"},
                 @{name="name"; type="string"}}
$typeJ = ConvertTo-Json $type -Depth 3 -Compress

$schema = @{schema = "$typeJ" }
$schemaJ = ConvertTo-Json $schema -Compress
```

This produces the following...

```
{"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"namespace\":\"customer-actions\",\"name\":\"customer-enrollment\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"int\
"},{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}"}
```

Which looks really bad; those escaped quotes are all required. The same escaped characters are used with simpler schema without problems.

Thanks in advance.

[Edit]
The call to Schema Registry API if it helps

```
curl -Uri http://server:8081/subjects/customer-enrollment/versions `
     -Method Post `
     -ContentType "application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" `
     -Body $schemaJ
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem was the - character in the name customer-enrollment

```
$type = @{namespace="customer-actions"; name="enrollment"; 
          type="record"; 
          fields=@{name="id"; type="int"},
                 @{name="name"; type="string"}}
$typeJ = ConvertTo-Json $type -Depth 3 -Compress

$schema = @{schema = "$typeJ" }
$schemaJ = ConvertTo-Json $schema -Compress
```

Is there a term for when you find the answer yourself immediately after posting a question in a public forum?

Comment: validator here [AVRO Schema Validator](https://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/avro.jsp)

Comment: Not sure if a term but what happened to you is like [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: The validator link ^ was really helpful because in my case the type was incorrect. it does not take "integer" but "int"

Comment: Thanks for the validator link!